# while loop not ending in java even after condition is satisfied in multithreaded popgram

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program, which is showing weird behavior in one certain condition. Due to the proprietary issue, I cannot post the complete code here, but I am putting the example bug here.

I have one class which has a boolean variable and is extending Java Thread class

```
public class SystemStreamCapture extends Thread {

    InputStream is;
    boolean done = false;
    List<String> buffer;

    private final static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(SystemStreamCapture.class);

    public SystemStreamCapture(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.buffer.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
            isr.close()
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.error(ioe);
        } finally {
            this.done = true;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return this.buffer;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return this.done;
    }
}
```

This Thread is used inside other class as follows:

```
public class FileReader {

    private final static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class);

    public List<String> readLines(FileLineRequestModel request) throws IOException {
        String[] script = { "/bin/sh", "-c", request.getCommand() };
        Log.debug("executing line fetch command : " + request.getCommand());

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);

        SystemStreamCapture errStream = new SystemStreamCapture(p.getErrorStream());
        SystemStreamCapture outStream = new SystemStreamCapture(p.getInputStream());

        errStream.start();
        outStream.start();

        while (!outStream.isDone()) {
            // keep looping
     //Log.debug("reading...");
        }
        return outStream.getData();
    }
```

The weird part is while loop in the later class. Loop never ends despite "done" variable getting "true". I also tried syntax '`(outStream.isDone() == false)`', just to see whether it makes any difference or not (which I know will not).
However as soon as I turn '`Log.debug("reading...")`' inside while, it works as expected.

I have no idea whats happening, maybe outStream.isDone() call tries to copy boolean into new memory address and the relentless polling is not allowing it.

Please share your experience and knowledge on this issue.

Comment: Without looking at that pile of code, one rule: close your streams in a `finally` statement, or use try-with-resources.

Comment: Did you check the documentation to see how you're supposed to read `getErrorStream` ? there is a check if it's still `available()` that you're not using. For more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: Make `done` `volatile`.

Comment: Try marking `done` as `volatile`.  And to make it thread safe without having to synchronize yourself perhaps change to `AtomicBoolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In multi-threaded environment you required visibility when one thread change one value should visible to other thread.For your case you can use  `volatile boolean flag` or use `AtomicBoolean` variable type so it will visible to other thread when one thread changes the value.

```
volatile boolean done = false;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to show _which_ variable should be `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps.

Comment: @vaibhav singh   If you think it works for you  up vote so it will be helpful for other.